# Global var in function with arguments

Tags: javascript, global

I have:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="add-to-cart-button" onClick="javascript:addToCart([@id]);">Add to cart</a>
```

and Javascript:

```
var pid;
function addToCart(id){
pid = id;
}
alert(pid);
```

It return 'unidentified'
How can I assign value from addToCart(id) to pid? thanks!

Comment: what is `[@id]`? that's not HTML

Comment: which language u are using to get [@id] ?

Comment: [@id] will return product id, its like {id} id smarty

Answer (score 3):

Your `pid` is undefined when you're loading the page. To show the actual value you have to put the alert inside the function:

```
var pid;
function addToCart(id){
    pid = id;
    alert(pid);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QD3Hn/)

Comment: is there anyway to assign id (local) to pid (global), Couse I want to use pid in another function like "function abc(pid)". Thank you!

Comment: @user1906288 yes, there is a way, and you're doing it. You need to work out execution order, however.  If you are wanting to use the value outputted by `[@id]` during page load, you'll need to output it somewhere other than just an `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is executed during pageload to

1. declare a variable named `pid` *(declare only, no value defined)*
2. declare and define a function named `addToCart` *(declare and define, not execute...)*
3. alert the declared `pid` variable *(which has yet to be defined as any value)*

Also, during pageload, your markup is parsed, and the JavaScript engine defines *(but does not execute)* a click handling function which will call `addToCart()` *when the element is clicked*.

**It is when the element is clicked that `addToCart` will be run, giving `pid` a definition, and this is all after the `alert` took place during page load.**

Alerting within your `addToCart` function after setting `pid`, however, will show you the proper value.

Also, see comments and answers regarding `@id`.

As an added note, the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol you're using at the start of your `onclick`attribute is not appropriate in that attr, and has been deprecated where it used to be appropriate (such as in an `href` attr). You should remove it and cease all use of it.